# Keeping local changes after git Untracked Files Prevent Merge

Tags: git, github-actions

I have an Android app in GitHub which uses an API key.
I have set it up in my `local.properties` and ignored it in `gitignore`.
However, in order for GitHub Actions to build my app, it looks for a `local.properties` file with a certain key, and as it is ignored, the build process fails. I created a fake `local.properties` in GitHub with an empty key and it works (the tests don't need to see the map itself, but they just need the app to compile and run), but unfortunately, whenever I try to pull from the remote, I get:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    local.properties
```

Of course, I want to keep the local copy of `local.properties` as it is the one that contains the valid API key.

What can I do in order to prevent this, so I can be able to push and pull, and have the project built but without exposing my keys?

Thanks!

Comment: Write your action to create `local.properties` (perhaps from `default.properties` or `local.properties.example` or some similar name) if it's missing, or just always. Then, *don't* commit one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create the fake `local.properties` file in your workflow instead of committing it. Then it will only exist temporarily.

```
      - name: Create local.properties
        run: echo "apikey=empty" > local.properties
```

Alternatively, commit a file with a different name and rename it just before building.

```
      - name: Create local.properties
        run: mv local.properties.fake local.properties
```